# My soft brushes in photoshop seem to be pixelated when I use them, how do I make them smooth again?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, art

In Photoshop CC, whenever I use the soft brush on a particular area, the brush seems to be pixelated rather than it's usual smooth. When I zoom in, it only gets worse and the pixelated lines start to move in motion. I've lost so much time because of this problem, and I've definitely made sure that I'm on the correct layer mode, tool, and presets because it has been working up until this point. Any solutions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you see if **Noise check box** is unchecked in the Brush panel?

Comment: @LeoNas yes, it's unchecked. I sent the pixelated image to my phone from my laptop and it seems to be smooth showing up on my phone, so it may be some kind of bug with my computer rather than the brushes.

Comment: Yes. That was my thought too. Some memory or video card issues can cause smoothing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change the **brush** blend mode, not the layer blend mode, back to normal. It's probably set to `Diffuse`. (Control Bar with a brush selected)

[image]